# SSE integer 2^n powers of 2 for 32-bit integers without AVX2

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I can't find an SSE instruction for computing `2^n` for a vector `__m128i` of 32-bit integers.

Is there an instruction or function that does the following pseudocode?

```cpp
__m128i power_of_two(__m128i b) {
    __m128 r;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        r[i] = 1 << b[i];
    return r;
}
```

The `_mm_sll_epi32` instruction only computes `r[i] = a[i] << b[0]`.

Comment: Per-element shift counts don't exist until [AVX2 `_mm_sllv_epi32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpsllvw:vpsllvd:vpsllvq).  If you can't just use that, you have to emulate it e.g. with unpacking and blending ([SSE2 shift by vector](//stackoverflow.com/q/38605451)).  Or for right shift with different but constant shift counts, multiply and shift [Shifting 4 integers right by different values SIMD](//stackoverflow.com/q/38363423).

Comment: For your case where the value being shifted is a constant `1`, x86 can do that very efficiently for scalar (with `bts reg, reg` given a zeroed destination).  But with SSSE3 you might be able to build something out of `pshufb` as a lookup table.  If your counts are always `<= 7` (or maybe `<= 15` with more work) then `pshufb` is perfect.  If all 4 counts are always near each other (leading bits the same), then you could separate counts into bits-within-a-byte for `pshufb` in the low byte, and then a `_mm_sll_epi32` with the common prefix they all share.  (So AND / ANDN to separate them).

Comment: There's a float hack for this too

Comment: Also related: [AVX alternative of AVX2's vector shift?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36637315)

Comment: @harold: oh right!  Bias the count and stuff it into the exponent field, then convert that FP bit-pattern to integer.  That's probably best for throughput if you don't have any restrictions like `count < 8`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no single instruction pre-AVX2, but even with just SSE2 there is a trick that abuses the floating point format to generate powers of two by generating the exponent field with integer arithmetic and then converting that from a float to an integer. There may be faster options.

```
__m128i power_of_two(__m128i b) {
    __m128i exp = _mm_add_epi32(b, _mm_set1_epi32(127));
    __m128 f = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_slli_epi32(exp, 23));
    return _mm_cvtps_epi32(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to think about float tricks with SSE more often.